# What is the word for 'not good at expressing words / thoughts / emotions in person'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Kind of like:

- not good at expressing oneself

Comment: Have you looked in a thesaurus or a dictionary for antonyms to verbose? reticent or diffident, for example? There are many words for *not expressing*. Without a bit more context, it's hard to guess which one is best.

Comment: Socially inept?

Comment: Emo... I kid, i kid.

Comment: It depends quite a lot on the reason for the behaviour: If the person is not verbose because they choose not to talk, they are taciturn, reticent or reserved; if it is because they are not good at talking, they are inarticulate or poorly spoken. (Though you would only know such when they do talk!)

Comment: Is "in person" the critical point? As in, they can _write_ words and thoughts, and adequately convey their emotions in writing; but get all flustered and tongue-tied trying to do it face to face (or in front of a group)?

Comment: Obviously, 'inarticulate' and 'succinct' are very different. I've voted to re-open because of this, then CV-d for lack of research.

Answer (score 9):

Well, "not good at expressing oneself" sounds like "inarticulate."  "Not verbose" sounds like "quiet," or perhaps "reticent."

Answer (score 5):

*Timid* seems like a good option here, since you seen to be indicating that **in-person** is key.

I think that perhaps *taciturn* could work even better.

Answer (score 5):

"Tongue-tied" might describe that red-faced, ear-ringing, throbbing jugular panic that accompanies sudden speechlessness in the moment of truth.

Answer (score 1):

I think [reticent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Reticent) may give the idea:

> Inclined to keep one's thoughts, feelings, and personal affairs to oneself.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single word I can think of.

However, the usual expression is ***poor verbal communication skills*** (a mouthful, but that's what it is.)

See [Verbal Communication](http://www.selfgrowth.com/articles/Definition_Verbal_Communication.html) on selfgrowth and [Communication Skills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_skills) on WP.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Cerebrotonic](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/14657/cerebrotonic)** Designating a personality type characterised as intellectual, introverted, and emotionally restrained.
>
> **[Reserved](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reserved)**: formal or self-restrained in manner and relationship; avoiding
>   familiarity or intimacy with others: a quiet, reserved man.
>   4. characterized by reserve, as the disposition, manner, etc.: reserved comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference once to [Alexithymia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexithymia) in a biographical work and was intrigued by the concept. Wikipedia says: "*a personality construct characterized by the sub-clinical inability to identify and describe emotions in the self*".

After doing some research, it is actually a specific medical term used for clinical diagnosis: A person who might appear as an automaton in both personal and social situations. However, in the biographical work I was reading, it was used much more loosely. For example, men raised in broken families, perhaps in inner-city, survival-of-the-fittest environments, will have trouble later in life showing emotion, forming attachments and expressing love, and the author uses the word "alexithymia" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Reserved would be a good option when the person chooses to keep her/his thoughts to herself/himself.

Answer (score 0):

[Stilted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stilted) also a possibility:

> (Of a manner of talking or writing) stiff and self-conscious or unnatural

Answer (score 0):

wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=dyslogia

see the word dyslogia- impaired ability to express ideas verbally.

for inability to express thoughts in written, consider agraphia.

if this doesn't satisfy you then choose the answer voted most.

Answer (score 0):

Verbally (conversationally) challenged.

A euphemism is "visual learner".

Answer (score 0):

How about "ineloquent," lacking eloquence?